# Dealing with (birthday) dates and Timezone with Dojo

Tags: date, timezone, dojo

I have a simple widget that has:

```
<input class="input" id="${id}_dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" />
```

Note that it's a birthday. So, it's meant to stay the *same*, regardless of where you are when you are (timezone shouldn't happen). If you are born on the 10th of January at 3:00AM in England, and view your personal information from New York, you are meant to still see 10th of January, NOT the 9th!

I am in GMT+8 right now.
When I submit this form, this actually gets to the server when I put in 1/1/1970:

```
dateOfBirth: "1969-12-31T16:00:00.000Z"
```

Which is bad, because it's 8 hours short of the actual date.

Basically, I need a way for the DateTextBox to show the date *as* it came from the server, effectively ignoring the browser's timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much hacking and analysing Dojo's source code, I came up with this:

```
var UTCDateTextBox = declare( 'UTCDateTextBox', [ DateTextBox ], { 


  _getValueAttr: function(){ 
    var ov = this.inherited(arguments); 
    if( ov ){ 
      ov.setTime( ov.getTime() - ov.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000 ); 
    } 
    return ov; 

  }, 

  _setValueAttr: function( value, priorityChange, formattedValue){ 

    var v = stamp.fromISOString( value ); 
    if( v ){ 
      v.setTime( v.getTime() + v.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000 );                         
      value = v; 
    } 

    this.inherited(arguments); 
  }

});
```

Basically:

- When the value is set, the timezone difference gets added. This means that if the server has 1979-12-25T00:00:00.000Z, rather than assigning Tue Dec 25 1979 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST), it will assign Tue Dec 25 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST) . Basically, the date is converted *locally* to whatever it was in UTC.
- When the value is parsed, it will be changed from Tue Dec 25 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST) to Tue Dec 25 1979 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST)
- The changed value is the one submitted to the server. So, it will be correct regardless of what timezone it will be edited at.

Since I only ever ever deal with dates, if the server has 1979-12-31T23:00:00Z (which is an error: for birthdays, the time is actually ignored and mustn't matter), this will happen:

- When the value is set, ISO is 1979-12-31T23:00:00.000Z. So, Tue Jan 01 1980 07:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST) is changed into Mon Dec 31 1979 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST). This means that the right date is placed into the date textbox (31/12/1979).
- When the value is parsed from the textbox, Mon Dec 31 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST) becomes Mon Dec 31 1979 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (WST). So, the server will save 1979-12-31T00:00:00Z -- which is, again, the correct date!

If there are bettere solutions, please let me know. Frankly, I hope there are as this one feels like a *bit* of a cheat!

Comment: Oh my God, either my answer (which continues to work well) was "the" answer, or nobody is recording birth dates using Dojo's date picker!

Comment: I don't think there's a canonical way to do this without extending the calendar (like you've done) or manipulating the Date before serializing it. In my own projects I've handled it in a similar manner.

Comment: And still no upvotes, which means that not many people actually care about this. Oh well...

Comment: Great job Merc. I needed a UTC text box for "seasonal" date ranges on a vacation rental website. I've been using a hack for such a long time.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, here is my variant of UTCDateTextBox:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/form/DateTextBox"
], function(declare, DateTextBox) {
    function isValidDate(value) {
        return value instanceof Date && isFinite(value.getTime());
    }
    function toUTCDate(value) {
        if (isValidDate(value)) {
            value = new Date(
                Date.UTC(value.getFullYear(), value.getMonth(), value.getDate())
            );
        }
        return value;
    }
    return declare(DateTextBox, {
        _getValueAttr : function() {
            return toUTCDate(this.inherited("_getValueAttr", arguments));
        }
    });
});
```

For my use case, I found that I didn't need to override `_setValueAttr()`.  With the above implementation, when `getUTCXXX()`, `toUTCString()`, `toISOString()` or `toJSON()` are called on the date object returned from `_getValueAttr()`, then the correct UTC date with zeroed time elements is returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a much better idea. Will test it out and accept this as the answer when I get home and test out this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've used this widget in our application.